# C++ And Or Boolean

Tags: c++

shall we add exor or or operation to add two numbers ?

How can we add two numbers by boolean operations ? I have designed a Full Adder Before.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main(void)
 {
     int x=2;
     int y=3;
     int z =x | y;
     cout<<z;
     getch();
     return 0;
 }
```

How Can I XOR if I Should TO XOR ?

Comment: Review your boolean algebra.

Comment: OPPS you right, I will change !

Comment: @tenfour - Should write that as an answer - it exactly explains why this doesn't work.

Comment: @Parkhid, ok now that you have removed the only clue as to what the issue is, you should add back what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take care of the carry bits.

Comment: can you explain more opeartion! I think I should XOR that

Comment: I know carry Look Ahead , But What is the XOR Operator in C++?

Comment: Thanks I Got it : A XOR B = ANotB + BNotA.

Comment: You need another variable for carry bits. You need to operate iteratively over the bits rather than in a single operation.

Comment: @Parkhid: `A^B` is the XOR operator.